# How do I make it so that the code will ask you your name again if the user answers no after my if statement?

Tags: python

Here is my code:

```
fullName = input("Hello there, what is your name?")

fName = (fullName[0:fullName.index(" ")])

sName = (fullName[fullName.index(" ")+1:])

print("So, your first name is", fName)
print("and your second name is", sName)
answer = input("Is this correct")
```

Here is where I'm having most of my issues, everything before this works fine to my knowledge:

```
if answer == "Yes" or answer == "yes":
    print("Great, lets get started!")
elif answer == "No" or answer == "no":
```

Comment: Did you read this before posting?

Comment: @jonrsharpe, dude im new to this I only started coding a week ago, I think i formatted it better now. Also do you have any clue what to do here?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just a simple and quick answer, maybe there is easier way.

```py
fullName = input("Hello there, what is your name?")
fName, sName = fullName.split()

print("So, your first name is", fName)
print("and your second name is", sName)
answer = input("Is this correct?")

while not (answer == "Yes" or answer == "yes"):
    fullName = input("Hello there, what is your name?")
    fName, sName = fullName.split()
    print("So, your first name is", fName) 
    print("and your second name is", sName)
    answer = input("Is this correct?")
```

Comment: Thanks, the code worked, now ill be able to continue on.